# How can I read lines from a file in Typo3?

Tags: typo3

I have to read in a big file in Typo3 (Version 6.2.10) in a plugin we wrote. The file is uploaded via the backend and as it changes it will be newly uploaded.

Currently I use:

```
$file->getOriginalResource()->getContents();
```

`$file` is a `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference`.

That works fine, as long as the file in question is small enough. The problem is, that the content of the file is read in the memory completely. With bigger files I reach the point, at which this fails. So my question is, how can I read in the contents of the file line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy it to a temporary local path with

```
$path = $file->getOriginalResource()->getForLocalProcessing(false);
```

Then you can use `fgets` as usual to loop through the file line by line.

Comment: That's exactly what I found out in the meantime and do now. I forgot to provide this solution as an answer, thanks for doing so. I accept it, as I use this solution now and it works.